# What is the difference between P(A) and P(A $\cap$ B') for two independent events?

Tags: probability, independence

I am finding it difficult to understand the following concept in elementary probability (or I might be just confused). Given the probability of two **independent** events A and B, how does the probability of A occurring, P(A), differ from the probability of **only A** occurring, P(A $\cap$ B')?

When I draw a Venn diagram, the area occupied by P(A) and P(A $\cap$ B') looks the same, but it doesn't seem right for them to be equal.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: They are the same if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, which I'm assuming is how you drew your diagram.  Try drawing one where $A$ and $B$ overlap a little bit.

Comment: Remember that $P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B')=P(A)$ by the rule of sum or the rule of total probability.  You should know how to calculate $P(A\cap B)$ since they are independent and you should know $P(A)$ from the problem statement.

Comment: @tilper brings up a good point.  It is likely that you confused the terms "mutually exclusive" and "independent."  These are very different concepts.  $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive if and only if $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  That is, $A$ and $B$ don't overlap.  On the other hand $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$ if and only if $Pr(A)=Pr(A\mid B)$.  That is, if $A$ and $B$ overlap the ratio of the size of $A$ to the overall space is the same as the ratio of the intersection of $A$ and $B$ to $B$.

Comment: Recall that **independent** $A,B$ satisfy $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, while **disjoint** $A,B$ means $P(A\cap B) = 0$.  So these notions are different in general.

Comment: Yes, it seems I've confused the terms "mutually exclusive" with "independent". As @tilper mentioned, the probabilities are the same if A and B are disjoint.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is *not* the same region in the Venn diagram:

[image]

$A$ is regions I and II, while $A \cap B'$ is only region I

Note that region II is $A \cap B$, so that's part of $A$.

Indeed, $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B')$

Comment: @ZacharySelk .. then $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ .... not sure where you are going with this ...